# run vb script using script.exe

Tags: c#, .net, process.start, wsh

I want to run vbscript file using cscript.exe.
i searched a lot but did'nt found any way while i can run my script using cmd with cscript.exe

this is my code

```
Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\\Program Files\\VDIWorkLoad\\WorkLoadFile\\open test.vbs";
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "testing";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            try
            {
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
```

any idea how i can use cscript.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the FileName property to the executable you want to run. In your case that would be `cscript.exe` and not `testing`:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\Program Files\VDIWorkLoad\WorkLoadFile\open test.vbs""";
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe";
```

Comment: can you guide me when i try to run my script using system.diagnostic.start(path); it works fine but when try to execute using window service it does'nt work any idea?