# Call a VBS in C# to open a itemTemplate Outlook

Tags: c#, vbscript, outlook

I need some help because I'm having some troubles..

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and coding in C#. A little application.

I explain my issue :

I have a button who calls a script file `name_script.vbs`

On the `name_script.vbs` :

```
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("PATH")
myItem.Display
```

In C# button :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\Patch_to_the_script\name_script.vbs");
```

I have put on the top of my application :

```
Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

In my laptop is working but in other laptop not working
If I open directly the `script.vbs` It's works ! Directly !

But in others laptops, **Error:** `ActiveX can't create object 'Outlook.Application'`..

I have launched with cscript but no changes ..

Maybe a problem in the compilation with a DLL ?

Did you have some ideas of this problem ?

Thanks in advance

---

I also try this :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();


    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder f = application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts)
       as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail =
        application.CreateItemFromTemplate(@"\\Path\template.oft", f)
        as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;

    mail.Display();
```

and this :

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process repousse= new Process();
    string targetDir = string.Format(@"\\path\");
    repousse.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir;
    repousse.StartInfo.FileName = "script.vbs";
    repousse.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    repousse.Start();
    repousse.WaitForExit();
```

And here to : [Cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850834/run-vb-script-using-script-exe)

Comment: I am not getting you properly. But based on your question i think that you are trying to build something. And trying to call a file located in folder named "Patch_to_the_script". Did you built your program in 64 bit machine and are trying to call it in 32 bit or vice-a-versa? Or there is no folder there named Patch_to_the_script? OR there is no installation of OUTLOOK in that laptop or something else? I am sure that it must be from somethings like this.

Comment: The folder it's okay
I have built with AnyCPU in Visual Studio and in x86 but no changes.
All the machines are in 32bits.
They have all Outlook 2010.

On my laptop "Dev" -> It works.

If I try with cscript.exe -> I have the window cscript and after it cclosed and nothing after

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the client machine doesn't have the appropriate classes registered for Outlook interop. This could happen for an enumerable number of reasons, some of which include:

- Office isn't even installed,
- Outlook isn't installed,
- The client interop libraries weren't installed when Office was installed,
- Office needs repaired because its class id's are messed up in the registry,
- The `.vbs` extension isn't registered properly,
- The wrong version of Office is installed,
- Etc.

Though there are other reasons that could be the culprit, I believe one of the aforementioned are likely the issue. Further, the `using` statements in your application are irrelevant. The `.vbs` file isn't going to use those `using` statements.

Comment: Okay, I see..
Difficult to see who is really the problem. It's possible to install the DLL when the user launche the .exe ?

Comment: @user3046640, it's unlikely you'll be able to fully configure the client when you try and run the script. You'll need to get the client configured. You need to go through each of these items and see if they are true.